# Best strategy to pick a lock which opens if at least two of its three decimal digit wheels are dialed correctly?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you want to open a lock with three digits code, the lock is a little special because it can be opened if you have two digits guessed right. To clarify, if the correct three digit is `123`, then guess `124` or `153` can open the box. The lock looks like this:

[image: a rendered picture of a three decimal digit lock]

**Question is: what is best strategy to open the box?** The best strategy is a strategy which requires least attempts at average. You should also find the average.

The strategies I came up with are:

First strategy: hold first digit, and constantly change second and third while keep them equal when changing them. For example, I will try: `111`, `122`...`199`,`211`,`222`,...,`299`,....

Second strategy: hold second and third equal, and constantly change first one. For example: `111`, `211`,...,`911`,`122`,`222`,...

**I don't know if these two are best, nor do I know if they are equivalent efficient.**

### Edit

[Here is a program](https://jsfiddle.net/31ds8ux4/3/) to calculate the average number of trails for a strategy from an ardent comment. To use it, replace the line '// Input your list here' with your test list and press run.

Comment: Does "best strategy" mean fewest guesses, least movement of the wheels, or some other criterion?

Comment: I'm thinking fewest guesses ... Intuitively, I think I would just ignore one of the digits and have the other two go through the 100 possibilities in any order ... but I don't know if that's right

Comment: Further clarification: fewest guesses **on average**?  or fewest guesses **in worst case scenario**?

Comment: @JMoravitz fewest guesses **on average** should be fine.

Comment: It seems the "specialty" in this lock reduces the guess space from 1000 to 300. The brute froce way would be to ignore one digit and try 99 combinations with the other two and repeat three times.

Comment: @DavidK means fewest guesses. Remember every time you try a combination, you need to switch the key to open a box.

Comment: @darksky But if you go through all 100 combinations of two digits, then for one of those the lock should open. So why is it not 100? Why 300?

Comment: @Bram28 100 should be the maximum..

Comment: @fizis Exactly. And I have a sneaking feeling you can't do better than just going through all 100 in any order. Like I said: just ignore 1 digit, and try the other two in any order. I don't there is any more efficient way to do it ... but I could be wrong :)

Comment: @Bram28 I don't think so, on average when you turn the last two digit together, you may meet the wanted number twice when you give ten trails.

Comment: @Bram28 my mistake. 100 should be the upper bound.

Comment: @fizis I see: if the digit you leave alone is correct, then with your method you have two chances of getting a second digit correct. And if it is not correct, then it doesn't matter. So yes, your method should be better!

Comment: @fizis But after trying 10 combinations you change the first digit (this is your first method) ... at that point I would try different combinations for the 2 others, i.e. proceed with 223, 234, 245, 256, etc. That way, you also get some additional chances of hitting on the last two digits possibly being correct.

Comment: @Bram28 I think keep second and third at a constant difference should equal to my first strategy.

Comment: @fizis I don;t think so.  After you have tried the 10 options with the first digit at 1, you know the last 2 digits are not 11,22,33, ..., so after changing first digit to 2, try 23,34,45, for the other two digits. That should increase your chances of getting a hit, not between the first digit and one of the others, but with the two other digits by themselves

Comment: @Bram28 You are quite clever, the strategy should modify during the crack! Because we have already know some impossibilities.

Comment: @fizis I think that's why your second strategy is not optimal either: after 111 you know the last two are not 11, so 211 gives you less chance of a hit than, say, 212. ... but now it seems we're basically back to the first strategy.

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, you are absolutely right.

Comment: So: the optimal strategy is ... whatever you try next, try and have it something that has at least two digits different from all the things you already tried ... and do that in a sequential way so that you can make sure there is a new number that has a 'two_digit_different_distance' from all tried numbers as many times as possible? ...

Comment: @Bram28 Sounds interesting, why not form your idea into an formal answer?

Comment: There are 300 good combinations.  1000 total.  Each wrong guess eliminates 30.  After 10 completely different guesses you eliminated 300 and there are only 700 left.  However you can no longer have completely different guesses.  Each new guess can only reduce 27 guesses, I think reducing to 430 left.  Hmmm, I think the in 10 more guesses we can rule out 240 with 190 left and get it in the next 10.  so within 50 guesses.  I think.  I could be wrong.

Comment: @fizis Pretty sure I cracked it! Thanks for the puzzle and dialogue: you showed my initial response was wrong. Team work!

Comment: For optimizing the number of tries in the worst case, the optimal solution is to use an optimal [covering code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_code) with alphabet size $q=10$, length $n=3$, and covering radius $R=1$. The optimal size seems to be $50$ (see PDF number 4 [here](http://www.sztaki.hu/~keri/codes/)), so $50$ tries is the best possible worst case when optimizing worst case. This question asks for average, but I think that with proper ordering of the tries, the optimal covering code might be better than given in the answers now. I'll try this soon.

Comment: @fleablood In the beginning, each wrong guess eliminates $1+ 3 \times 9 = 28$ possible combinations (not $30$): the one that you guessed, and then in each $3$ digits there are $9$ possible other values.

Comment: A program to test the max-tries and average tries of any list: https://jsfiddle.net/31ds8ux4/1/ (You can add this to the question if you'd like)

Comment: @ThijsterHaar Thanks, I will add that program to the question, it will save other's time.

Answer (score 25):

I have a strategy with at most $50$ tries and $22449/1000=22.449$ expected tries.

$$
\begin{align}
443, 796, 869, 101, 230, 577, 314, 022, 965, 656, \\
588, 757, 875, 213, 140, 331, 689, 998, 404, 410, \\
134, 303, 241, 886, 555, 667, 779, 421, 599, 000, \\
432, 202, 897, 768, 044, 033, 695, 342, 011, 976, \\
678, 959, 112, 858, 987, 224, 123, 320, 566, 785\phantom{,}
\end{align}
$$

This was obtained by starting from the unordered set of these words (given by a covering code) and then ordering them using a greedy computer search; more details below.

---

First, I'll get some ideas by considering another problem, *optimizing the number of tries needed for the worst case*, which has a known solution for this case. A [covering code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_code) $C$ with alphabet size $q=10$, length $n=3$, and covering radius $R=1$ is a set of $3$-tuples (called *words*) of length $3$ over $\{0,1,\dots,9\}$ such that every possible $3$-tuple differs from one in $C$ in at most one position. This is exactly what we need.

The minimal size with these parameters is $50$ [1]. It contains these words:
$$
\begin{array}{|ccccc|}
\hline
000 & 011 & 022 & 033 & 044 \\
101 & 112 & 123 & 134 & 140 \\
202 & 213 & 224 & 230 & 241 \\
303 & 314 & 320 & 331 & 342 \\
404 & 410 & 421 & 432 & 443 \\
\hline
555 & 566 & 577 & 588 & 599 \\
656 & 667 & 678 & 689 & 695 \\
757 & 768 & 779 & 785 & 796 \\
858 & 869 & 875 & 886 & 897 \\
959 & 965 & 976 & 987 & 998 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

For any two columns, the upper half contains a word for all $25$ pairs of symbols in $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ that can occur there, and the lower half contains all $25$ pairs of symbols in $\{5,6,7,8,9\}$ that can occur there. The correct combination has to contain at least two symbols from either set, so it is opened by entering one of these words.

[1] Some sources refer to "J. G. Kalbfleisch and R. G. Stanton, A combinatorial theorem of matching, J. London Math. Soc. (1), 44 (1969), 60–64; and (2), 1 (1969), 398", but I can't find the paper. However, the value is listed in the fourth PDF listed at the top of [this page by Gerzson Kéri](http://www.sztaki.hu/~keri/codes/).

---

Now back to the original problem, *optimizing the expected number of tries required*. My idea is to try to take these words and optimize the order somehow. This of course doesn't guarantee that we have an optimal solution.

I tried a greedy random approach: Choose words one by one. At each step, for each possible new word $c$, find the number of previously uncovered words that would be covered by $c$. Then among the ones that cover the most, choose one by random. After some time, the best that I could find was the order given at the top of this answer, with $22449/1000$ as the expected number.

Comment: Nice! Beats my strategy! +1!  A proof would seem to be difficult though, no?

Comment: Beats my strategy.

Comment: Do you think you can get it down to 45 of by doing 011 to 099, then 101-180 , 202-270, etc.?  Just taking a wild guess.

Comment: The average trails is calculated by computer or by hand?

Comment: Would you please elaborate more about why you choose the trails from that `50` "magic" numbers?

Comment: @fizis It is one of the optimal solutions for the worst case, so I thought it might be a good starting point for the average case because it maximizes the average number of new words covered by each trial. I don't know whether the actual optimal solution for the average case is using these words in some order, and even if it is, the proof might well be very complex.

Comment: @fizis I calculated the average with a computer, but it is exact because there's just 1000 possible cases, so you can for example just enumerate over them and see the number of trials needed for each case.

Comment: @fleablood The claim that 50 is the smallest possible number has been repeated in peer-reviewed mathematical literature since 1969, so I don't expect to go below that. :) And I don't know how to interpret "101-180": going 101, 112, 123, ... would end in 189 and 190, not 810, and I see no other obvious continuation.

Comment: With a logical approach (instead of your greedy random approach) I can only get up to 22.500 expected tries. I really don't understand where that 1 extra try comes from.

Comment: @ThijsterHaar If you have that logic approach, you can write about it. To my understanding, this answer just set an upper bound. The approach itself is not deterministic, for the using of the algorithm is random greedy.

Comment: Interesting fact: The series for the problem with $n$ary numbers matches http://oeis.org/A000982 for all published $n$ in your source $(1,...,21)$. The series is $1, 2, 5, 8, 13, 18, 25, 32, 41, 50, 61, 72, 85, 98, 113, 128, 145, 162, 181, 200, 221$.

Comment: @DanielR That's true; after writing the answer I found out that the theorem in the paper I refer to is that the number is indeed $\lceil n^2/2\rceil$ for all $n$.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Did you eventually find the paper?

Comment: @JiK well, obviously no-one here is familiar with the paper.  I was thinking as the pattern presented here went from 000-044 and then 101-134,140, and 202 to 240 etc. and then doing it all over again for the values higher than five, if it'd be more efficient to go all the way to 9 rather than 4 and then it can be done in 10+9+8+7+....+1 = 45 steps.  Except, of course, 10 + 9 +8 + 7+....+1 = 55 not 45.  Oops. ... $⌈n^2/2⌉ $for all n.  That looks really familiar.  I think some other representation this would have been easier.

Answer (score 4):

OK, so the basic idea I have is as follows:

We want to cover as many possible combinations as possible for each try. Thus, for example, the OP's strategy of doing 111,122,..., followed by 211,222, ... would seem less than optimal, since the first 10 tries already cover any combinations with the last two digits being the same. So, it would be better to do 111,122, ... followed by something like 223,234,245, so that not only do you try to get a hit between the first digit and any of the other two, but you are also trying other options to get a hit between the 2nd and 3rd digit.

In fact, even 111,122,... is less than optimal, since they both cover 121, so you get overlap. So, it's probably best to start with something like 111,222,333,... since each of these covers 28 combinations without overlap.

After that, I figure we should just keep making sure that every new try we make has as few digits in common with whatever combinations we already tried up to that point... basically try and make each combination differ in 2 digits from any of the ones tried before. The following sequence will do exactly that (each sequence of 10 has a unique difference between 1st and 2nd digit, between 2nd and 3rd, and between 1st and 3rd):

000, 111, 222, 333, ..., 999, (at this point we have covered 10*28=280 combinations)

012, 123, 234, 345, ..., 901, (another 10 * 22 (e.g. 012 covers itself and 3*7 more) = 220)

(so with a mere 20 tries we cover half of all possible combinations!)

024, 135, 246, 357, ..., 913, (another 10 * 18 (this takes some writing out) = 180)

036, 147, 258, 369, ..., 925, (another 10 * 12 = 120)

048, 159, 260, 371, ..., 937, (another 10 * 8 = 80)

(at this point, don't proceed with 050,... since that has two digits in common with earlier 000)

051, 162, 273, 384, ..., 940, (another 10 * 5 = 50)

063, 174, 285, 396, ..., 952, (another 10 * 4 = 40)

075, 186, 297, 308, ..., 964, (another 10 * 2 = 20)

087, 198, 209, 310, ... ,976 (the last 10)

In an earlier version of my answer I said to do another 10 after these:

099, 100, 211, 322, ... , 988

the idea being that this would cover all possible pairs of 1st and 2nd digit, and thus covering all possible combinations (and thus we would have a worst case of 100). However, it turns out that whichever ones these additional 10 would cover have been covered already by the previous 90.  So, worst case of this method is 90 tries, not 100.

The above method gives an average of 0.28*5.5 (the first 10 tries each cover 28 cases, so that is 280 cases out of 1000 is 28%, which on average take (1 + 10)/2 = 5.5 tries) + 0.22*15.5 + 0.18*25.5 + 0.12*35.5 + 0.08*45.5 + 0.05*55.5 + 0.04*65.5 + 0.02*75.5 + 0.01*85.5 = 25.2 tries to open the box.

I really think this method cannot be improved in terms of average number of tries, but I have no proof.

**Edit** ok, so this is *not* the most efficient strategy: see JiK's answer! Time to eat humble pie! ...  Well, I hope at least I was able to express some of the ideas why some strategies might be better than others.

Comment: worse case scenario is no better than fixing the first digit and guessing the other two.

Comment: True. No matter what method, worst case is always 100 tries.  But I think this method optimizes average number of tries

Comment: That seems to be a good strategy

Comment: Why not just 000 to 009, then 110 to 119, then 220 to 229, etc?  This seems to capture the essence of your strategy but more simply.

Comment: Oh, wait, I get it.  If you do 000 then you already *know* that the answer doesn't have two 0's, so there is no point in trying 001 since that can't be the right answer.  Very nice solution.

Comment: @Wildcard Right.  But you were right to show the sequence starting with 0's, rather than 1's, so you see the pattern a bit more clear. I changed it accordingly. I think it looks better now. Thanks!

Comment: @JiK Thanks for the suggestion! I just did.

Comment: Strange that a guess that seems suboptimal and doesn't even contain a _sketch_ of a proof would be the top answer.  -1

Comment: @Can you add something how you calculate the average of your strategy? For example, why 0.28*5.5...

Comment: The average you calculated is not sound... See others will say about it. You can highlight that part and wait for comment.

Comment: @fizis Why do you think it is not sound?

Comment: The true random variable is the actual code, which is from `000` to `999`. You need to compute the corresponding trails needed for every possible actual code, then sum them up, then divide  by 1000.

Comment: Someone have implement a program to calculate the average trails, see my edited question.

Comment: @fizis Yeah, I saw that. I entered my list and got ... 25.2!

Comment: Ok, let me rethink your expectation value calculation. Thanks, your strategy is very good, totally based on reasoning, wonderful.

Comment: @fizis Thanks!  And yes, it's exactly the logic behind the approach that allowed me to calculate its average pretty quickly by hand.

Comment: Can you find in which step, you have "double count" a possibility?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with entropy, in each try you want to maximally lowerize the entropy.

Since I forgot the formulas for entropy I'll go this way... Maximize the probability to unlock in each try.(it's kinda same)

Let n be order of the try and p(n) probability to unlock, then:

$p(1)=\frac{3*9+1}{1000}=\frac{28}{1000}$

After first try you discriminate 28 combinations, so if you failed with 111, you also know that 112,113,...,121,... are not the combination

Lets try your second strategy for the next try, if you pick 211, you will discriminate another 18 combinations (212,213,...210,221,231,...230 but combinations 311,411... you already discriminated, so p(2) with the 2nd strategy is $p(2)=\frac{18}{972}$

Lets try 1st strategy, so second pick to be 122, this way you discriminate another 26 combinations cos 121 and 112 were already disc.

So I would decide for strategy to change all three digits, to discriminate another 28 combinations, so $p(2)=\frac{28}{972}$

That's what would you do for the first 10 tries, and for the rest... try on your own :)

Comment: But it is not clear that if for every new number you pick, you pick the one that discriminates the most number of combinations, that then you get the minimal number of guesses on average. For example, maybe by picking a combination that discriminates 10 other combinations (as opposed to one that discriminates only 9), I am being 'locally greedy', and the best subsequent move may only be able to discriminate 6 (for a total of 16 between the two moves), while the other move has a subsequent move that discriminates 8 (for a total of 17 between the two moves).

Comment: @Bram28 you are right, it is possible that in a moment, maybe, the better probability in the next try doesn't mean better strategy in total. It should be taken care in the late moves, when numbers are low and divisibility is matter.

Comment: At least this establishes a lower bound on the worst-case number of tries. You cannot "cover" more than $28$ combinations per try, so it will take at least $\lceil 1000/28 \rceil = 36$ tries.

Comment: I think theoretically this might be a right direction.

Answer (score 1):

So, what if you reduced the question to just 3 possible numbers allowed for each digit?

From $000$ to $222$

In that case, you can cover any of the 27 permutations with just 6 guesses
$$000$$
$$111$$
$$222$$
$$010$$
$$020$$
$$101$$

So that's 6 guesses to get $3^3$.  I'm not sure how this would generalize though.

Is it $n^2\frac{n-1}{n}=n(n-1)$ which would be 90 in your problem? (This generalization also works for the near-trivial example of only 2 numbers, 0 and 1, in which case 000 and 111 covers any permutation)

Also, this method is trying to minimize worst case, exhaustive method, not the average number of tries.

**Edit**: Confirmed $n(n-1)$ also covers every options in base 4 (from 000 to 333).

000, 111, 222, 333,

012, 013, 021,

102, 103, 120,

210,

301

And from what I gather from brute force methods, in your original question, cycling through the 000, 111, 222, 333....999 will take out 28 permutations each, for 280. After that, you will be able to make 80 guesses that will take out 9 permutations each, for a total of 90 guesses that cover all 1000 permutations.

Also, after 29 guesses, you've taken out over 500 of the permutations.

Answer (score 1):

1) 000: Rules out more than 1 zero

2-4) 011;101;110: Rules out one and zero and more than one 1

25-28) 022;202;220;....099;909;990:  Rules out 0 and more than 1 of any number.

29-34) 123,213,231,132,312,321: Rules any two of 1,2,3

35-52)145...167...189: Rules out any 1s; and any pair of (4,5)(6,7),(89)

53-58)246....642: Rules out 2s with 4or 6 and any pair of 4 or 6.

59-64) 257....752: Rules out 2s with 5 or 7; so only 2s with 8 or 9 are left.  But 8 and 9 can't pair so this is impossible so, rules out 2s.

65- 70)347...743: Rules out 3s with anything less than 5s.

71-76) 356..653: Rules out 3s with anything other than 8 and 9, which is impossible so rules out 3.

4s are only possible with 8 and 9 so that's impossible.

6s are only possible with 8 and 9.  7 is only possible with 8 or 9.

So any combination we would have guessed in 76 guesses.

I'm not sure how to generalize.